# Rails3: Base#after_update has been deprecated

Tags: callback, ruby-on-rails-3, deprecated

I see the warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Base#after_update has been deprecated, please use Base.after_update :method instead. (called from <class:City> at /home/petrushka/webdev/my_app/app/models/city.rb:4)
```

What should I write instead of

```
  def after_update
     ....
  end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should write as follow:

```
after_update :your_custom_method # macro-style
```

at least you can pass a block instead of a method:

```
after_update do |model| 
  model.name = model.name.capitalize unless model.name.blank?
end
```

more info here: http://guides.rails.info/active_record_validations_callbacks.html (choose rails edge documentation)