# rails - after_update deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I noticed that [after_update is deprecated](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_update) in Rails now.

If I want to fix this, would this just be a switch to [after_save](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save) instead?

I need to track down where in my application this is occurring and make sure that it's not in any imported Gems, but the `after_save` documentation appears to indicate that it *should* work and my basic test application appears to confirm it.  I just thought I'd ask in case anyone has had any experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use new syntax: `after_update :<method_name>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3178997/2611078